# How to legally stay in Hong Kong and keep working at my company while it has no office in HK?

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, student-visa, hong-kong

My company has an office in Singapore and I really love working with them. We have flexible working hours, can work remotely, can work from another country. But I really want to move to Hong Kong where we have presence at all. I have a working visa in HK that ends soon. And I have an EP (working visa) in Singapore.

I was thinking maybe I can get some sort of student visa and keep working with them whilst also studying something useful.

Anybody knows any legal ways? Maybe there's some way to a hassle-free business opening or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an HR company to do the visa process in the stead of your employer. Your employer signs a contract with a local HR company, which recruits you and sponsors your visa. Your employer pays your salary and a fee to the HR company, and the HR company pays you your salary, and usually provides group medical insurance.

Source: been there done that.

## Edit

Note: this has tax consequences (and possibly visa-related consequences in Singapore), as you will have to get your salary in HK, not Singapore, and pay taxes there. You will not be employed in Singapore any longer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please elaborate a bit on that? I didn't quite get it. So if my employer has no office nor business in HK but I want to live in HK and I'm not a citizen nor am I a permanent resident in HK my company can contact local HR company in HK for them to "hire" me to work for them (HR company) so they will be handling visa things and get some fees for these services but I'll still will be working (remotely) with my current company?

Comment: A few more questions. How that affects my next job in Hong Kong? Am I still officially employed with my company or with HR company? Taxes in HK and MPF (pension fund)? Is it going to affect  my application for Permanent Residency/Citizenship?

Comment: That's the process indeed. My (former now) employer did it with Adecco HK, but any big HR company will be able to do this. As for your employment status, you can mention on your CV your Singapore employer. You're employed by the HR company only in the eyes of HKID, which knows what's really happening anyway. Taxes and MPF are the same. The HR company will help you file taxes. And there's no (negative) effect on your PR.

Comment: Weird, I reached out to Adecco and they said they can't do this unless my employer has some presence in Hong Kong. Trying to clarify. Did your company have an office in HK?

Comment: Not the first year. When I received I was working from home.